# Highcharts: How to add a text panel on the side of the chart area

Tags: jquery, charts, highcharts

I would like to add a side panel, where I add text, to a Highcharts chart.

I can't find thou, a way to keep everything in the same container.

When I render the chart; it takes the whole space of the container; as expected; and if I set the container as smaller; it still render the whole chart at the size that you specify in the chart option.

How do you actually tell Highcharts to draw the plot and stop at a certain percentage of the width of the chart, so I can add text there? (instead than add text on top of the chart, which is ugly and messy).

Comment: You should refer Highcharts Renderer API on this link: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Renderer which allows to add HTML elements on the chart area

Comment: I have made a fiddle demonstrating how to add text elements to the chart ! May be that can help you a little bit !

Comment: Hmm, I have used renderer but I don't understand exactly how do you use it in this context...do I create a chart rendered that is smaller inside the main chart? Any example is more than welcome; I am a bit slow on these things :) Thanks!

Comment: It would be great if you create a working fiddle of your code and provide link to it ! It will help us to find effective solution.

Comment: I tried today to make a fiddle and for the love of the gods; it works fine in a web page but won't work in the fiddle...even when I use someone else's fiddle, and put my code in, it won't work. I need to install Firefox and try with that; I have Safari as browser (should not matter but makes no sense to me).

Comment: You can submit us your code so we can also try to create a fiddle out of it

Comment: Sounds good; adding it to the top of the question. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To force highcharts to leave more space on the right, you can use the 'marginRight' attribute:

```
chart: {
        type: 'line',
        borderWidth: 1,
        plotBorderWidth: 1,
        marginRight: 200
    },
```

Similarly, there is a marginLeft if you want the space on the left.

http://jsfiddle.net/mt9UM/